# Remove function in a Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a header file called StringList.h that includes the following:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class StringList;


class StringListNode
{
    friend class StringList;
private:
    StringListNode * pPrev;
    string data;
    StringListNode * pNext;
};

class StringList
{
public:
    StringList();
    ~StringList();
    void addToBottom(string s);
    void addToTop(string s);
    void remove(string s);
    string print();
    void clear();
    bool isEmpty() {return (pTop==NULL);}
private:
    StringListNode * pTop;
    StringListNode * pBottom;
};
```

My StringList.cpp file will have the definitions to all my functions.
So far I figured out how to addtotop and addtoBottom works

addToTop:

```
if(isEmpty())
    {
        StringListNode * pNewNode;
        pNewNode = new StringListNode;
        (*pNewNode).data = s;
        pTop=pNewNode;
        pBottom=pNewNode;
        (*pNewNode).pPrev = NULL;
        (*pNewNode).pNext = NULL;
    }
    else //it's not empty
    {
        StringListNode * pNewNode;
        pNewNode = new StringListNode;
        (*pNewNode).data = s;
        (*pNewNode).pNext = pTop;
        (*pTop).pPrev = pNewNode;
        (*pNewNode).pPrev =NULL;
        pTop=pNewNode;
    }
```

addToBottom is basically the same but replacing pTop with pBottom in the else statement.
Now, where im stuck is at remove. I want to go through each nod until it finds the string within *data and delete it. However i dont really know how to make the previous pointer to the node i want deleted point to the pNext of the next node. Any suggestions?

print():

```
string StringList::print()
{
    string result;
    StringListNode * pCurrent;
    pCurrent=pTop;
    while(pCurrent!=NULL)
    {
        result+=(*pCurrent).data+"\n";
        pCurrent=(*pCurrent).pNext;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why would the `print()` function return a `string` by value?  Why not make StringListNode a private nested class?  (If the function `print()` returns a string, it presumably does not also actually print the string or list to standard output as the name suggests it would/should.)  Also, there's a marvellous operator, the arrow operator or `->` which means that `(*pNewNode).pPrev = NULL;` can be written more clearly as `pNewNode->pPrev = NULL;`, etc.

Comment: My function that i have written returns a string called result

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Check my edit. print() works just fine. My problem is remove()

Comment: "how to make the previous pointer to the node i want deleted point to the pNext of the next node" - you have to maintain two pointers, one for the previous, and one for the currently checked node.

Comment: A more conventional name for `print()` would be something like `toString()`.  You are not printing the list; you are converting it into something printable (a string).  Just letting you know that the name is misleading for most people.  Also, if you don't want people to be distracted, create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) without extraneous functions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I dont really understand the point of your argument but ok! Its print for print to screen. This a StringList that just happens to be in a linked list format. Im printing string values because thats what im working with. Strings

Comment: OK — we're talking past each other.  The one thing your `print()` function does not do is 'print to screen'.  It creates a string representation of your entire linked list, ready for printing to screen or file or anywhere else, but it does not actually do the printing even though its name suggests that it does.  Not a big deal; it's your code and you can call it what you like — but don't expect other people to be happy with your choice of name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have three nodes in a doubly-linked list and you want to delete the middle node, identified by `curr`:

```
 curr ----------------------+
                            |
                            v
       +--------+       +--------+       +--------+
...----| pPrev  |<------| pPrev  |<------| pPrev  |<---...
       | Node 1 |       | Node 2 |       | Node 3 |
...--->| pNext  |------>| pNext  |------>| pNext  |----...
       +--------+       +--------+       +--------+
```

The two relinking operations are:

```
curr->pPrev->pNext = curr->pNext;  // Previous node's next points to curr's next
curr->pNext->pPrev = curr->pPrev;  // Next node's previous points to curr's previous
```

You can now dispose of `curr` in any suitable way.  The only trick is dealing with end-cases; what happens when you delete the node at the start or end of the list, or the only node in the list.  What's appropriate depends on how you've created your list.  Do you have null pointers, or a circular list, or ...

Given that you use null pointers to mark the ends of the list, you have to check for null pointers when deleting.

```
if (curr->pPrev != 0)
    curr->pPrev->pNext = curr->pNext;
if (curr->pNext != 0)
    curr->pNext->pPrev = curr->pPrev;
```

You also have to deal with `curr` being the head of the list, adjusting the head (`pTop`) or with it being the tail of the list, adjusting the tail (`pBottom`).  You also have to deal with `curr` being the only node in the list.

Superficially working code...not validated with `valgrind`.  However, the repeated use of the `toString()` member function (née `print()`) suggests that the list structure is OK.  No promises about no leaks.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class StringList
{
private:
    struct StringListNode
    {
        StringListNode *pPrev;
        string          data;
        StringListNode *pNext;
    };
public:
    StringList() : pTop(0), pBottom(0) {}
    ~StringList();
    void addToTop(const string &s);
    void remove(const string &s);
    string toString();
    bool isEmpty() { return (pTop == NULL); }
private:
    StringListNode *pTop;
    StringListNode *pBottom;
    StringListNode *find(const string &s);
};

string StringList::toString()
{
    string result;
    StringListNode *pCurrent = pTop;
    while (pCurrent != NULL)
    {
        result += pCurrent->data + "\n";
        pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
    }
    return result;
}

StringList::StringListNode *StringList::find(const string &s)
{
    StringListNode *sp = pTop;
    while (sp != 0 && sp->data != s)
        sp = sp->pNext;
    return sp;
}

void StringList::addToTop(const string &s)
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        StringListNode * pNewNode = new StringListNode;
        pNewNode->data = s;
        pNewNode->pPrev = NULL;
        pNewNode->pNext = NULL;
        pTop = pNewNode;
        pBottom = pNewNode;
    }
    else
    {
        StringListNode * pNewNode;
        pNewNode = new StringListNode;
        pNewNode->data = s;
        pNewNode->pNext = pTop;
        pNewNode->pPrev = NULL;
        pTop->pPrev = pNewNode;
        pTop = pNewNode;
    }
}

void StringList::remove(const string &s)
{
    StringListNode *curr = this->find(s);
    if (curr == 0)
        return;
    if (curr->pPrev != 0)
        curr->pPrev->pNext = curr->pNext;
    if (curr->pNext != 0)
        curr->pNext->pPrev = curr->pPrev;
    if (pTop == curr)
        pTop = curr->pNext;
    if (pBottom == curr)
        pBottom = curr->pPrev;
}

StringList::~StringList()
{
    StringListNode *next;
    for (StringListNode *sp = pTop; sp != 0; sp = next)
    {
        next = sp->pNext;
        delete sp;
    }
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    StringList s;
    s.addToTop("abc");
    std::cout << "After add abc: " << s.toString();
    s.addToTop("def");
    std::cout << "After add def: " << s.toString();
    s.addToTop("ghi");
    std::cout << "After add ghi: " << s.toString();
    s.addToTop("jkl");
    std::cout << "After add jkl: " << s.toString();
    s.remove("def");
    std::cout << "After del def: " << s.toString();
    s.remove("ghi");
    std::cout << "After del ghi: " << s.toString();
    s.remove("abc");
    std::cout << "After del abc: " << s.toString();
    s.remove("jkl");
    std::cout << "After del jkl: " << s.toString();
    return 0;
}
```