# Functions that manage a linked list

Tags: c++, function, linked-list

I have a class called StringList than has multiple functions that manage and manipulate a linked list of strings. I have an AddtoTop which adds to the top of the list, AddtoBottom, a function called add which adds a string but places it in alphabetical order, a clear function, a find function, print and a remove function. I have written every single function, however i have one main issue. When i use "AddtoTop" and "AddtoBottom", I add a string to the linked list. My remove function works when i ask to remove a string that i placed using those two functions only. When i try to remove a word i added with the "add" function, my program crashes. The function "remove" (shown below) can remove strings that were added using the "AddtoBottom" and "AddtoTop" functions but not the strings added using "add" Can anyone help me figure out why? Im trying to re write it a different way but i get stuck. Here are my functions:

```
StringList::StringList() //constructor
{
    pTop=NULL;
    pBottom=NULL;
}

StringList::~StringList()  //destructor
{
    StringListNode *next;
    for (StringListNode *sp = pTop; sp != 0; sp = next)
    {
        next = sp->pNext;
        delete sp;
    }
}
void StringList::add(string s) //adds and places in alphabetical order
{
    if(pTop)
    {
      if( s < pTop->data )
        {
            StringListNode *A=new StringListNode;
            A->data = s;
            A->pNext = pTop;
            pTop = A;   // new top
            return;
        }
        // go further into list
        StringListNode *iter = pTop;
        while( iter->pNext )    
        {
            if(  iter->pNext->data < s )
                iter = iter->pNext;
            else
                break;
        }   
        StringListNode *in=new StringListNode;   //actuallly inserts node
        in->data = s;
        in->pNext = iter->pNext;
        iter->pNext = in;
    }
    else// new item 
    {
        pTop = new StringListNode;
        pTop->data = s;
        pTop->pNext = NULL;
    }
}

StringList::StringListNode *StringList::find(const string &s) //basic search function
{
    StringListNode *sp = pTop;   // Search
    while (sp != 0 && sp->data != s)
        sp = sp->pNext;
    return sp;
}

void StringList::addToTop(string s) //add to top of nodes
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        StringListNode * pNewNode;
        pNewNode = new StringListNode;
        (*pNewNode).data = s;
        pTop=pNewNode;
        pBottom=pNewNode;
        (*pNewNode).pPrev = NULL;
        (*pNewNode).pNext = NULL;
    }
    else //it's not empty
    {
        StringListNode * pNewNode;
        pNewNode = new StringListNode;
        (*pNewNode).data = s;
        (*pNewNode).pNext = pTop;
        (*pTop).pPrev = pNewNode;
        (*pNewNode).pPrev =NULL;
        pTop=pNewNode;
    }
}

void StringList::addToBottom(string s) // add to bottom
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        StringListNode * pNewNode;
        pNewNode = new StringListNode;
        (*pNewNode).data = s;
        pTop=pNewNode;
        pBottom=pNewNode;
        (*pNewNode).pPrev = NULL;
        (*pNewNode).pNext = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        StringListNode * pNewNode;
        pNewNode = new StringListNode;
        (*pNewNode).data = s;
        (*pBottom).pNext = pNewNode;
        (*pNewNode).pPrev =  pBottom;
        (*pNewNode).pNext =NULL;
        pBottom=pNewNode;
    }
}

string StringList::print() //prints strings in linked list
{
    string result;
    StringListNode * pCurrent;
    pCurrent=pTop;
    while(pCurrent!=NULL)
    {
        result+=(*pCurrent).data+"\n";
        pCurrent=(*pCurrent).pNext;
    }
    return result;
}

void StringList::clear()   //clears everything
{
    pTop = NULL;
    pBottom = NULL;
}

void StringList::remove(string s)  //removes a string
{
    StringListNode *curr = this->find(s);
    if (curr->pPrev != 0)
        curr->pPrev->pNext = curr->pNext;
    if (curr->pNext != 0)
        curr->pNext->pPrev = curr->pPrev;
    if (pTop == curr)
        pTop = curr->pNext;
    if (pBottom == curr)
        pBottom = curr->pPrev;
}
```

Comment: If possible, is there a better way to write this remove function to work more efficiently?

Comment: Your `add` method is only singly-linking the new items into the list - it's leaving the `pPrev` members uninitialized.

Comment: @JonathanPotter So my remove function works correctly? Ok let me see if i can work some magic on that pPrev. Any suggestions though?

Comment: @WestonBuckeye Please edit your question to include your question rather than posting it as a comment.

Comment: You should also provide a `main()` function which illustrates the steps that you describe in English.

Comment: You really should be passing the strings by `const string &s` as in the answer to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635481/remove-function-in-a-linked-list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
void StringList::add(string s) //adds and places in alphabetical order
{
    if(pTop)
    {
        StringListNode *iter = pTop;
        while (iter && s > iter->data)
            iter = iter->pNext;

        if (iter)
        {
            // insert before
            StringListNode *A=new StringListNode;
            A->data = s;
            A->pNext = iter;
            A->pPrev = iter->pPrev;
            if (iter->pPrev)
                iter->pPrev->pNext = A;
            else
                pTop = A;
            iter->pPrev = A;
            return;
        }
    }

    // add to bottom
    addToBottom(s);
}
```

Note that you're probably better off using a `std::set` (or `std::multiset`) rather than rolling your own list code as that will keep the strings sorted automatically, and lookups and random inserts are generally in logarithmic time rather than linear.

Comment: hey man! sorry i never responded. I got it to work a different way but this also works like a charm! Thanks for your help i appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

A major problem with the `add()` code as written is that it does not set the `pPrev` pointer (but should).  Draw yourself a diagram similar to the one I used in my answer to the 'how to remove' question, and see what assignments you need to make as you add a new node.

It is also worth thinking about 'how could I check that the data structure is sound'?  For example, at each node `curr` in the middle of a list, you should be able to assert:

```
assert(curr->pPrev->pNext == curr);
assert(curr->pNext->pPrev == curr);
```

Adjusting for end pointers being null, you might write:

```
assert(curr->pPrev == 0 || curr->pPrev->pNext == curr);
assert(curr->pNext == 0 || curr->pNext->pPrev == curr);
```

Your `add()` code does not ensure that these invariants are maintained.  You also face a problem; if the list is being maintained by `addToTop()` or `addToBottom()` then using `add()` is not going to work reliably because the list is not guaranteed to be in sorted order.

Also, as I showed (but didn't specifically discuss) in my answer to your previous question, you should really pass the strings around as `const string &s` rather than using `string s`.  It has quite an impact on the efficiency of the code, in general.